# "query LIMIT 1" takes forever whereas "... WITH x LIMIT 1 query" is instantaneous

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Version info:

```
{
  "edition" : "enterprise",
  "version" : "3.2.2"
}
```

I have a Neo4j database with several million instances of label U and label D. Every U is connected to exactly one D by relationship WITH_D. Several Us may share the same D. My goal is to get a D and a list of all Us connected to it.

Why is it that this first query hangs for an indefinite amount of time...

```
match (d:D)<-[:WITH_D]-(u:U)
return d, collect(u) limit 1
```

Whereas this one returns immediately in a few ms?

```
match (d:D) with d limit 1
match (d)<-[:WITH_D]-(u:U)
return d, collect(u)
```

The query plan for the first involves node-by-label scan yielding millions of nodes, then "Expand all" yielding millions of nodes, whereas the second one is a node-by-label scan with a filter down to one node, and then "Expand all".

It seems like there are issues with the way limits are handled, i.e. in some cases it is simply not lazy enough.
This leads to a lot of unwieldy subqueries to avoid non-terminating queries. With a database nearing 1 billion nodes, I have encountered this issue many times. Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the main point here is the place were you are using the `LIMIT 1` in the query.

In the first query you are `MATCH`ing **ALL** possible patterns between a `:D` and `:U` labels first. In the end of the query you are limiting the result to 1. That is: you are matching all patterns and using `LIMIT` "as a filter" over the entire result.

In the second query you are `MATCH`ing `:D` nodes **limiting to one**. After, you are getting all `:U`s connected to this single node. That is: the first `MATCH` is being finalized when the fist occurrence of `:D` node is found. So the `LIMIT` is being used at **read time** and not only before the entire result is returned.

Comment: You are right, that is what the text of the query is saying - but I believe these two queries should have identical results and identical performance.
Consider the case where we want to just get 1 node. We would write,


    match (n) return n limit 1


Obviously we don't expect this to first get *all* nodes, then just trim to the first. The execution engine is lazy in this case, as it should be, and just gets one node then quits. I'm guessing the "collect" aggregator is what's tripping up the query planner here.

Comment: @user19650 I believe that the problem here is the way you understood the `LIMIT` statement. A `LIMIT` is not relative to the entire query, but to parts of it. You can use `LIMIT` to constrains the number of rows in the output of a `RETURN` or  `WITH`. For example, you can do:  match (d:D) with d limit 1
match (d)<-[:WITH_D]-(u:U)
return d, collect(u)

Comment: @user19650 In your first query the LIMIT is relative to the WITH. In the second query, the LIMIT is relative to the entire RETURN.

Comment: @user19650 These queries will definitely not return identical results in all cases. Consider in the second query if the `:D` node you matched and limited to does not have an incoming :WITH_D relationship from a :U node. In that case you will have no results. The first query can only return no results if no such pattern exists in the entire graph. Otherwise you're guaranteed a result, and a non-empty collection.

Comment: @InverseFalcon In general, that's true. At least in this particular database, no D exists without at least one attached U.